# Setting up SSH on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, putty

I'm trying to set up SSH on my Ubuntu system so I can log into my desktop computer remotely over the internet. I followed all the instructions here:
https://www.maketecheasier.com/setup-enable-ssh-ubuntu/

I've run into a couple of roadblocks. First, I don't actually know what username I should be using to try to log in. Nowhere in the guide did I set up a username... So I assume SSH is set up to use some sort of default username? I've tried a few potential usernames and none of them worked (e.g. I've tried "username", "root", and the username I use to log in when I'm physically at my desktop). Second, the passphrase I used to generate the rsa key, that is the password I should try to use to log in via SSH from a remote computer right? I've been trying that password with no luck.

If it matters, the machine I want to log in to is running Ubuntu 16.04 and the machine I'm using to try to log in is running Windows 10 and I'm using PuTTY to SSH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The username you should use is the username of one of the accounts that exist on the computer you are trying to connect to. So any account you created on your computer that runs the SSH server should work. However, keep in mind that [sometimes the default config of your SSH server might prevent you from accessing your computer via SSH as `root`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/511833/cant-ssh-in-as-root).
2. The password you are supposed to enter is the one you use to connect to the account you chose, not your SSH passphrase.

So if you normally log into your computer with the username `bob` and the password `salad` (as an example), you would use the same credentials (`bob` / `salad`) when connecting to your computer via SSH.

Comment: That was not apparent to me at all based on the guide...but it works! Thanks!